In GoogleColab how to force line breaks?
While editing in GoogleColab, lines can be very long, they wraparound but there is no really a line break. So lines can become very large. Is there a way to have GoogleColab to break (\n, or add carriage return or something) after the line passes, say for example, 80 characters?
I am using the VIM editor in GoogleColab.
The problem is that when I am trying to move between lines it can have long jumps of over 10 visual lines, and moving to a place within the line needs to be through a character-by-character (with the arrow, for example) which slow down my displacement around the text.
One alternative is to fix long lines once they are created.
For example, in VIM you can type gq in escape mode , that would do it. However, although GoogleColab accepts the VIM editor is very limited and the gq command, or :set colorcolumn=72, for example, would not work in GoogleColab.
Here is the output of !vim version :
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Mar 14 2024 09:05:11) Included patches: 1-579, 1969, 580-1848, 4975, 5016, 5023, 5072, 2068, 1849-1854, 1857, 1855-1857, 1331, 1858, 1858-1859, 1873, 1860-1969, 1992, 1970-1992, 2010, 1993-2068, 2106, 2069-2106, 2108, 2107-2109, 2109-3995, 4563, 4646, 4774, 4895, 4899, 4901, 4919, 213, 1840, 1846-1847, 2110-2112, 2121 Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

Use gj and gk to go up and down a visual line - if it's supported.

Add the full output of $ vim --version from your shell, or the full output of :version within Vim.

@Friedrich : gj gk  will not work. My line is like 200 characters. I can see three lines but it is only one.  gj go to the next line, understanding "next" as separated by new line feed, no by the visual effect.

Too bad. You can still 80l, though.
